# i18next browser error:Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "i18next"

Tags: typescript, i18next

I'm using typescript+i18next.
the `i18next.ts`:

```js
import i18next from 'i18next';
export const defaultNS = 'common';
i18next.init({
    lng: 'en',
    fallbackLng: 'en',
    debug: true,
    resources: {
        en: {
            ...
        },
        de: {
            ...
        },
    },
});
export default i18next;
```

in tsconfig.json, set`"module": "ESNext"`.
and I import `i18next` in other files by using:`import i18next from '../i18n/i18n.js';`

when runs in the browser, shows

> error:index.html:1 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module
> specifier "i18next". Relative references must start with either "/",
> "./", or "../".

already tried:

1. delete node_modules and run `npm install` again.
2. delete complied file and run `tsc` again.